# Invalid object name of a temp table

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I'm salvaging Java code left for me from the previous employee, I was only left with the source code itself, I've had to recreate DB structure by myself. So far I fully restored it, but one line always throws exceptions at me and I can't understand why.

```
connBeztirazh.execSQLU("declare @ki table (ID_ki int); " +
"declare @bil table (ID_bilet int); " +
"insert into ki (i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6) output inserted.ID_ki into @ki values ("+i1+","+i2+","+i3+","+i4+","+i5+","+i6+"); " +
"insert into bilet(ID_ki,data) output inserted.ID_bilet into @bil values ((select ID_ki from @ki),(select SYSDATETIME())); " +
"insert into rezultat (ID_players, ID_bilet) output inserted.ID_bilet values ((select ID_players from players where telnomer='"+number+"'),(select ID_bilet from @bil));", false);
```

This line throws out the following exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'ki'.
```

I triple-checked everything, I recreated tables `bilet`, `players` and `rezultat`, they are used elsewhere in the code and everything's alright. As far as I understand SQL, ki and bil are temporary tables and since they are created and accessed in the same query there could not be any access/session problems.

Comment: I realize this code was dumped on you but you desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before little bobby tables comes to visit.

Comment: @ki and @bil are not temp tables, but are table variables.  In your first statement you have `insert into ki`, should this be `insert into @ki` ?

Comment: It doesn't look like it needs to be `INERT INTO @ki` because it has an `OUTPUT inserted.ID_id INTO @ki` later in the query.  It looks like it inserts into a table named `ki` and outputs the inserted id's to the table variable `@ki`.

Comment: You need to recreate the table `ki` - it is neither a temp table nor a table variable.  It is a physical table that is missing from your DB recreation.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks, I'll read on that topic. Luckily, this particular application is a proof of concept, I was asked to make it run for a couple of days to showcase an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I overlooked that in fact there are two tables: constant table `ki` and variable table `ki`. They are referenced by `ki` and `@ki` respectively, which is a really bad way to name your tables. After adding table `ki` to the database, everything started working as intended, as far as I can tell.

Thanks to everyone who commented on the post.